# Erro na execução de tarefas do gulp (task)

Tags: gulp, task, gulpjs, gulpfile

Alguém poderia me ajudar com esse erro?
Estou executando o comando "gulp" no cmd e aparece essa mensagem:

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (C:\Users\2018-0137\Downloads\gentelella-master\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
at Gulp.task (C:\Users\2018-0137\Downloads\gentelella-master\node_modules\undertaker\lib\task.js:13:8)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\2018-0137\Downloads\gentelella-master\gulpfile.js:60:6)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
```

**Segue também o código do aquivo gulpfile.js:**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

var DEST = 'build/';

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src([
        'src/js/helpers/*.js',
        'src/js/*.js',
      ])
      .pipe(concat('custom.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(DEST+'/js'))
      .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(DEST+'/js'))
      .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

var compileSASS = function (filename, options) {
  return sass('src/scss/*.scss', options)
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions', '> 5%'))
        .pipe(concat(filename))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(DEST+'/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
};

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return compileSASS('custom.css', {});
});

gulp.task('sass-minify', function() {
    return compileSASS('custom.min.css', {style: 'compressed'});
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: './'
        },
        startPath: './production/index.html'
    });
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('production/*.html', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('src/js/*.js', ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch('src/scss/*.scss', ['sass', 'sass-minify']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync', 'watch']);
```

**Arquivo package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Admin",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "css",
    "js",
    "html",
    "template",
    "admin",
    "bootstrap",
    "theme",
    "backend",
    "responsive"
  ],
  "author": "Saulo Lago",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "*",
    "gulp": "*",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "*",
    "gulp-concat": "*",
    "gulp-rename": "*",
    "gulp-sass": "*",
    "gulp-uglify": "*"
  }
}
```

Obrigado galera. Fico no aguardo.

Comment: Tente executar o comando em um terminal Unix, como `Git bash`

Comment: @IkaroSales no Windows?

Comment: Yesim :) Isso ai

Answer (score 0):

O motivo do erro deve ser a versão do seu gulp.
Ao invés de

```
gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync', 'watch']);
```

Tenta assim

```
 gulp.task('default', gulp.series('browser-sync', 'watch'));
```

Provavelmente esse cara pode dar error tbm

```
 gulp.task('watch', function() {
   gulp.watch('production/*.html', browserSync.reload);
   gulp.watch('src/js/*.js', ['scripts']);
   gulp.watch('src/scss/*.scss', ['sass', 'sass-minify']);
 });
```

Então você pode usar o mesmo comando acima gulp.series(), assim:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
   gulp.watch('production/*.html', browserSync.reload);
   gulp.watch('src/js/*.js', gulp.series('scripts'));
   gulp.watch('src/scss/*.scss', gulp.series('sass', 'sass-minify'));
 });
```